How do I add content dynamically in pdfmake?
I want to generate pdfs with pdfmake dynamically. I got everything working but the creation of dynamic rows based on data.
I simplified my code in this example:
getDocumentDefinition(img: string, data: DataResponse, user: UserResponse): TDocumentDefinitions {
    return {
        header: this.header(img),
        content: this.document(data, user),
        styles: this.applyStyles(),
    };
}

private document(data: DataResponse, user: UserResponse) {
     let rowY = 252;
     return [
         // works
         this.createRow(55, rowY, 1, { m: 10, s: 30 }, [163, 205], rowY + 6)

         // not working in loop
         data.map((item) => this.createRow(55, rowY, item.version, { m: item.minutes, s: item.seconds }, [163, 205], rowY + 6)).map(() => rowY += 34),
     ];
}

private createRow(rowX: number, rowY: number, version: number, time: { m: number; s: number }, x: number[], y: number): Content {
     return [
         this.createTable(10, version, time, {x: rowX, y: rowY}),
         this.circle(),
         this.circle(),
     ];
}

private createTable(heights: number, version: number, time: { m: number, s: number }, position: { x: number; y: number }): Content {
     return {
         table: {
             widths: ['10%', '30%', '30%', '30%'],
                heights: heights,
                body: [
                  [
                     {
                         text: version,
                         fontSize: 10,
                         borderColor: ['white', 'white', 'white', '#B3CCE6'],
                      },
                      {
                         text: time.m + 'm ' + time.s + 's',
                         fontSize: 10,
                         borderColor: ['white', 'white', 'white', '#B3CCE6'],
                      },
                      {
                         text: '',
                         fontSize: 10,
                         borderColor: ['white', 'white', 'white', '#B3CCE6'],
                      },
                      {
                         text: '',
                         fontSize: 10,
                         borderColor: ['white', 'white', 'white', '#B3CCE6'],
                      },
                   ],
                ],
            },
            absolutePosition: position,
        };
}

The methode createRow works outside of any loop but as soon as it is generated dynamically (see example above), the returning value is empty. I tried all kinds of loops and things but I cannot make it work. I would like to add single rows like this if possible. Any ideas on how to fix this? Is it possible to add content based on an array with an unknown size?


It looks like you're missing a comma in your return array in the document method, after this.createRow
data.map() returns an array, and when you include it within another array, you end up with a nested array
You have the same Y value for all dynamic rows; I believe it should be a dynamic value

I'd suggest smth like this:
private document(data: DataResponse, user: UserResponse) {
    let rowY = 252;

    const staticContent = [
        this.createRow(55, rowY, 1, { m: 10, s: 30 }, [163, 205], rowY + 6)
    ];

    const dynamicContent = data.map((item, index) => {
        let updatedRowY = rowY + index * someYIncrementValue; // Update this based on your needs
 
        return this.createRow(55, updatedRowY, item.version, { m: item.minutes, s: item.seconds }, [163, 205], updatedRowY + 6)
    });

    return [...staticContent, ...dynamicContent];
}


Thank you for your answer. I tried your solution but dynamicContent is still empty. Nothing is displayed and when I log it returns Array[ ].

Have you logged data inside the document method? Right before forming dynamicContent. So you're certain it's not empty?

I was certain because I got other data out of it before but it is EMPTY at this stage. Thank you for your help.

spread your result array of map. for ex:
private document(data: DataResponse, user: UserResponse) {
     let rowY = 252;
     return [
         ...data.map((item) => this.createRow(55, rowY, item.version, { m: item.minutes, s: item.seconds }, [163, 205], rowY + 6)).map(() => rowY += 34),
     ];
}

or use this
private document(data: DataResponse, user: UserResponse) {
         let rowY = 252;
         return data.map((item) => this.createRow(55, rowY, item.version, { m: item.minutes, s: item.seconds }, [163, 205], rowY + 6)).map(() => rowY += 34);
    }

Explanation: While you are calling without loop your function createRow returning as
[  [
         this.createTable(10, version, time, {x: rowX, y: rowY}),
         this.circle(),
         this.circle(),
     ] ]

but while in loop it is returning like this and adding one more array because map loop return array itself.
[ 
 [
  [
    this.createTable(10, version, time, {x: rowX, y: rowY}),             
    this.circle(),
    this.circle(),
  ] 
 ]
] 


Thank you for your answer. I agree that it probably is a bracket issue! Sadly both of your solutions return an empty array for me.

@Nati is data.map returning an empty array?
can you please console data inside of document function and check

it is empty... thanks for your help!
